# External access to Yun - request not recognised as HTML

Tags: wifi, arduino-yun, remote-control, h-bridge

I am trying to access my Yun externally.

My router recognises traffic on Port XXXXX and forwards it to my Arduino Yun.

I have the below code working internally and now trying to adapt this to work for external (adapted from http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TemperatureWebPanel).

To access the Arduino Yun over the network I type:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX/arduino/on
```

When using this script locally, i.e. `myArduinoName.local/arduino/on`, the onboard light turns on (and off if URL changed accordingly).

Adapting this working code, I have changed to "`noListenOnLocalhost`" and put in my port number (XXXXX).

The code is reached (see below for the response).

```cpp
#include <Bridge.h>
#include <YunServer.h>
#include <YunClient.h> 

// Listen on default port 5555, the webserver on the Yun
// will forward there all the HTTP requests for us.
YunServer server(XXXXX);
String startString;
long hits = 0;

void setup() {
  //Serial.begin(9600);

  // Bridge startup
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);


  Bridge.begin();
  Console.begin();


  // Listen for incoming connection only from localhost
  // (no one from the external network could connect)
  //server.listenOnLocalhost();
  server.noListenOnLocalhost();
  server.begin();

}

void loop() {
  // Get clients coming from server
  YunClient client = server.accept();

  client.println("hello");

  // There is a new client?
  if (client) {
    // read the command
    String command = client.readString();

    command.trim();        //kill whitespace

    client.println(command); // why does this return a full GET request instead of "on"?

    if (command == "on") {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delay(1000);   
    }

    if (command == "off") {
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delay(1000);              // wait for a second
    }


    // Close connection and free resources.
    client.stop();
    hits++;
  }

  delay(50); // Poll every 50ms
}
```

The response I get is (I have replaced my IP and port with X's):

> hello
>
> GET /arduino/off HTTP/1.1 Host: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX
>   Connection: keep-alive Pragma: no-cache Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch Accept-Language:
>   en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6

I expected

> hello
>
> on

So it would seem that because I'm using a different port (other than 80 or 5555) the response is no longer being interpreted as an HTTP request.

I have also tried to edit the uhttpd file via SSH to provide a specific address and port for both my external IP address and my fixed internal IP address.

Then tried to restart the device and also a uhttpd restart i.e.:

```
/etc/init.d/uhttpd restart
```

I have attempted to access the URL using my mobile phone (i.e. not on the same network).

Any ideas why my request is not being treated as HTTP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works!

The changes to the uhttpd must have done the trick to listen for http traffic on a given IP/port (other than 0.0.0.0:80).

Instead of supplying a port number for the server in the code, I would surmise that the change to the config takes care of it so this, so the port number in code is no longer needed:

YunServer server(XXXXX);

should be changed back to

YunServer server;